# Typesafe forName class loading

Tags: java, generics

How do I call `Class.forName()` when the result is a generic type? Usually I can use `asSubclass()`, but here the only way I see to do it is a cast, which kindof sticks out & bugs me when everything else is nicely typed with generics.

The scenario goes something like this:

There is a .jar with one entry point main class that has a `main()`. It takes an option of a classname (and some others, irrelevant here). The class given implements `Callable<Integer>`. This class is loaded, inited & launched.

Here is an example of what I need:

```
Class<? extends Callable<Integer>> clazz = (Class<? extends Callable<Integer>>) Class.forName(options.valueOf(className)).asSubclass(Callable.class);
```

Is there any way to get rid of that cast?

Using SE6.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you probably want a full generic `Class`

```
Class<Callable<Integer>> classCI = ...;
```

Then the java type system has no problem with

```
Class<? extends Callable<Integer>> clazz =     
    Class.forName(options.valueOf(className))
    .asSubclass(classCI);
```

How can we get `classCI`? We can cheat by unchecked cast

```
Class<Callable<Integer>> classCI = (Class<Callable<Integer>>)Callable.class;
```

---

This is inherently unsafe. There must be external forces to make sure the `className` really is a `Callable<Integer>`. For example if it's a `Callable<String>`, the program runs through all the casts without any problem, and it only blows up much later when `Integer call()` is invoked, and the error message will be very misleading.

It's ok if a cast cannot be analyzed statically to succeed:

```
Object o = ...;
String s1 = (String)o; // may fail, no javac warning
String s2 = String.class.cast(o); // may fail, no javac warning
```

as long as an exception is immediately thrown when the cast fails at runtime.

To be type safe, we must proactively check the generic type of the `className`

```
@SuppressWarning( "unchecked" )
Class<? Callable<Integer>> getClass(String className)
{
    Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
    via reflection, check generic super interfaces of clazz
    if there's no Callable<Integer> super interface
        throw "className is not a Callable<Integer>"

    // we have *checked*, the following cast is safe
    return (Class<? Callable<Integer>>)clazz; 
}
```

We are justified to suppress "unchecked" here, because the implementation *checks* to make sure that if the `className` doesn't really denote a class implementing `Callable<Integer>`, it immediately throws an exception right there. Our cast is "checked", and the program is type safe.

Comment: +1 : omg, I really would like to be so fit with generics so I could understand what's going on here.

Comment: Just FYI, the cast Class<Callable<Integer>> classCI = (Class<Callable<Integer>>)Callable.class doesn't work for some reason. Anyway, since I check for the Callable<Integer> via reflection, not that big a deal, just something to think about if you ever wanna edit this.