# Are Sets and Maps not parameterized?

Tags: java, generics, effective-java

In the first paragraph of Josh Bloch's book Effective Java's 29th Item it is said that

> it is the container that is parameterized

Doesn't the author discard Sets and Maps as parameterized types by above declaration?

Comment: No, he does not discard. Reread it.

Comment: All men are mortal. Sokrates is a man. Therefore, Sokrates is mortal.
//
Containers are parameterized. Sets and Maps are containers. Therefore, Sets and Maps are parameterized?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of Item 29 (as I just discussed in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45260466/113632)) is to demonstrate other usages of generics and paramterized types in addition to collections. The whole preceding chapter has essentially been discussing parameterized collection types, so Bloch is clearly not discarding `Map` and `Set` and other parameterized types - he is *distinguishing* them from a different type of pattern, which he calls a "heterogeneous container".

Compare an interface like:

```
interface Collection<E> {
  void put(E element);
  E get(int index);
}
```

with something like:

```
interface HeterogeneousContainer {
  <T> void put(Class<T> type, T instance);
  <T> T get(Class<T> type);
}
```

Notice that `Collection` itself has a type parameter, while `HeterogeneousContainer` does not. This is the distinction Bloch is trying to draw in this item - that you can use type parameters in more powerful ways than simply creating type-safe collections.