# Class design - manual cast alternatives

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, class-design

Question is related to classes below. Zookeeper1 and Zookeeper2 are 2 alternatives that I could use. I can potentially store in future different types of animals inside Zookeeper. I should be able to get those classes. In 1st case I store all animals in list (meaning in future I can add other new Animals easily), but I need to cast dog with (Dog) when I need to get it. Read somewhere that casts are code-smell, so I wanted to see if there are any alternatives? Other solution prevents casting, but has problem of adding new lists each time I add new animal.

```
class AnimalId{}

interface Animal{
    AnimalId getAnimalId();
    void breathe();
}

class Cat implements Animal{
    public AnimalId getAnimalId() { return null; }
    public void breathe() {}
}

class Dog implements Animal{
    public AnimalId getAnimalId() { return null; }
    public void breathe() {}
    public void bark(){}
}

class ZooKeeper1{
    Map<AnimalId, Animal> animals = new HashMap<>();    //future-proof

    void addAnimal(Animal a){
        animals.put(a.getAnimalId(), a);
    }

    void printAnimals(){
        animals.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key));
    }

    Dog getDog(AnimalId animalId){
        return (Dog)animals.get(animalId);  //NOK - must type-cast!
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZooKeeper1 zk1 = new ZooKeeper1();
        zk1.addAnimal(new Cat());
        zk1.addAnimal(new Dog());
        zk1.printAnimals();
        Dog d = zk1.getDog(new AnimalId());
        d.bark();
    }
}

class ZooKeeper2{
    Map<AnimalId, Cat> cats = new HashMap<>();
    Map<AnimalId, Dog> dogs = new HashMap<>();  //will need to add more lines in future

    void addCat(Cat c){
        cats.put(c.getAnimalId(), c);
    }

    void addDog(Dog d){
        dogs.put(d.getAnimalId(), d); //will need to add more lines in future
    }

    void printAnimals(){
        cats.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key));
        dogs.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key)); //will need to add more lines in future
    }

    Dog getDog(AnimalId animalId){
        return dogs.get(animalId);  //OK no type-cast
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZooKeeper2 zk2 = new ZooKeeper2();
        zk2.addCat(new Cat());
        zk2.addDog(new Dog());
        zk2.printAnimals();
        Dog d = zk2.getDog(new AnimalId());
        d.bark();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6541656/1553851

Comment: Its difficult to answer such general questions. Why do you have a `getDog` method in the first place - and why do you not have a `getCat` method? What certainly is a no-go is `return (Dog)animals.get(animalId);` because you did no type checking whatsoever beforehand, this method will simply crash half of the time...

Comment: @luk2302 instead getCat, I would use getAnimal since it has no Cat-specific methods. The code is just mock for making it simple to read (I guess there would be additional checks to make sure it is a Dog).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after looking into heterogeneous containers in Java, I guess this would be so far the best option I have? Any comments on this type of solution?

```
interface Animal { AnimalId getId(); }
class AnimalId { int id; AnimalId(int id){this.id = id;} public boolean equals(Object o){ return id==((AnimalId)o).id; } public int hashCode(){ return 1; } }
class Cat implements Animal { AnimalId id; Cat(AnimalId id){this.id=id;} public AnimalId getId(){ return id; } public String catSpecific(){ return "CS"; } }
class Dog implements Animal { AnimalId id; Dog(AnimalId id){this.id=id;} public AnimalId getId(){ return id; } public String dogSpecific(){ return "DS"; } }

class Zoo {
    private Map<Class<? extends Animal>, Map<AnimalId, Animal>> animals = new HashMap<>();

    public <T extends Animal> void assignAnimal(T animal){
        animals.computeIfAbsent(animal.getClass(), k -> new HashMap<>()).put(animal.getId(), animal);
    }

    public <T extends Animal> T getAnimal(Class<T> type, AnimalId animalId){
        return type.cast(animals.get(type).get(animalId));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Zoo zoo = new Zoo();

        AnimalId animalId = new AnimalId(1);
        Animal animal1 = new Cat(animalId);
        Animal animal2 = new Dog(animalId);

        zoo.assignAnimal(animal1);
        zoo.assignAnimal(animal2);

        Cat cat = zoo.getAnimal(Cat.class, animalId);
        Dog dog = zoo.getAnimal(Dog.class, animalId);

        System.out.println(cat.catSpecific());
        System.out.println(dog.dogSpecific());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine I wrote class `ZooKeeper1` without any knowledge of class `Dog` and passed it on to you. You then decide to extend the class and add the method `Dog getDog(AnimalId id)`.

Would you expect this to just work? If you see the gap in your reasoning, then you understand why casting is a bad idea.

Casting is a not a miracle solution. The only safe way to use it is to only cast objects of known types; for example, if you store a `Dog` instance in a variable of type `Animal`, then you know for sure that you can cast the result of `getAnimal(..)` to type `Dog`.