# Is there a way to automate casting in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, casting

I have a Map<String,Object> that I know contains Booleans, Doubles, Strings and also nested Maps and Lists that can contain the same set of types. I also know the fields and their types. The problem is that when I want to get a value from this map I have to write something like this:

```
double value = (double)((List<Object>)((Map<String,Object>)map.get("field_name")).get("another_field_name")).get(5);
```

and this doesn't look well and isn't the most readable piece of code. Of course I could write something like:

```
Map<String,Object> inner_map = (Map<String,Object>)map.get("field_name");
List<Object> inner_list = (List<Object>)inner_map.get("another_field_name");
double value = (double)inner_list.get(5);
```

to increase readability of this code a little but it's still not the prettiest solution.

So is there any proper way to get this casting done by a method or something?

Comment: Usually a collection contains a single type of value, for example all the elements in the collection are strings. Maybe you should re-visit why you decided to have multiple different types as the value objects in your `Map`.

Comment: Have you considered making proper classes from those dictionaries? Assuming this comes from JSON, there are plenty of libs that make this a breeze and the resulting code will be _much_ more readable and safer.

Comment: You can remove the cast to double by using `List<Double> innerList`.

Comment: @Abra - I don't have access to source code of the provider of this map. I don't know why someone chose to do this like that.

Comment: @tobias_k - it's not from JSON, it's some kind of binary format and the parser returns the data in the form of map so external library is not really an option.

Comment: @AndyTurner - I can't - this list also contains variables of other types.

Comment: So how do you know in advance what type will be associated with a given key?  You have to know in order to code the appropriate cast, so encapsulate that logic to provide a cleaner API for the rest of your code.  I.e. create a wrapper (facade/adapter) that knows how to do the casts and code the casts in one place only.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the "typesafe heterogeneous container" design pattern.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type safe heterogeneous container pattern to store lists of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541656/type-safe-heterogeneous-container-pattern-to-store-lists-of-items)

Comment: Yes, typesafe heterogeneous container design pattern was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.